# How can I split row data into alphabetical worksheets?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an Excel file with one source sheet containing many columns. Column 1 is text and column 2 onwards can be any format.

What I want is 27 more sheets in that same file named #, A, B, ... Y, Z.

As you can guess sheet # will contain all rows from source sheet (in the same order) where the first column starts with anything besides A-Z.

Same way sheet A will contain all rows from source sheet (in the same order) where the first column starts with A and so on.

The source sheet also has a header row which should be copied to all 27 new sheets.

I have been struggling and tried many things like group and filter and what-if but failed to understand how they work.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Which version of Excel? Also, is the data static or dynamic?

Comment: David I have 2007 with XP, 2010 with Windows 7 and 2013 with Windows 8. Sorry I am new to this - I don't know what is static or dynamic? It is just data in one source sheet. I got only the XLSX file from somebody and nothing more if that is what you are asking.

Answer (score 2):

*Remember to backup your file before performing any of this.*

Rather than `filter`, you should `sort` by the first column which will group the data together. From there you can select the rows of data you want to move, then cut and paste it to the sheet you need.

If some items appear to sort out of order, keep in mind the following from [How to correctly sort alphanumeric data in Excel](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322067):

> When you sort a column that contains alphanumeric characters, the sort
>   may return unexpected results. Excel sorts the values left to right,
>   character by character. For example, if a cell contains the text
>   "A100," Excel places the cell after a cell that contains the entry
>   "A1" and before a cell that contains the entry "A11."

---

You can create the tabs manually. If you haven't yet and want to automate the creation of the tabs, you can use this code pasted into `ThisWorkbook` in the VBA explorer (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>). Then run `AddWorksheets` from the macro window (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd>). When you are done, you can go back in and delete it from the macro window.

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1

Sub AddWorksheets()

    Dim Tabs As Variant
    Dim I As Byte
    Tabs = Array("#", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z")

    For I = LBound(Tabs) To UBound(Tabs)
        Sheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = Tabs(I)
    Next I

End Sub
```